# Why doesn't my app run on xlarge resolution of the GenyMotion emulator?

Tags: android, android-resources, genymotion

I am trying to run my app on a `GenyMotion` emulator(Custom Tablet) which has the following specifications:

1536 x 1152 dimensions.

320dpi-i.e xhdpi.

I have the following resources:

1.drawable-sw720dp-land-xhdpi

2.layout-sw720dp-land

3.values-sw720dp-land-xhdpi

I have the following code in the`mainifest` file:

```
 <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I have designed my app to work on small to xlarge screen resolutions. I have customized my emulator to work on mdpi,hdpi screens of the tablet, but in case of xhdpi the app doesn't take the xhdpi resources. Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: try to change sw720dp to sw600dp

Comment: I have designed for sw600dp too, but I want to test it for sw720dp.

Comment: what is size of tablet?

Comment: sw600 was for nexus 7 inch

Comment: in which device u r testing? what is size of that device?

Comment: GenyMotion online emulator. There is a Custom Tablet with 1536 x 1152 width and height

Answer (score 0):

by resolution you can't get actual size of device and sw720 is for 10 inch tablet and sw600 is for 7 inch tablet.

so the table in which you are testing is may be 7 inch tablet so it will use sw600. 
may this help you